# Faster alternative to get tags for objects than JVMTI GetTag

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jvm-hotspot, jvmti

When profiling with async profiler and gperftools I noticed that `jvmti->GetTag` shows up quite a lot in the results for my agent. When I checked how it is implemented I found the following in the source of `jvmitTagMap.cpp`:

```
jlong JvmtiTagMap::get_tag(jobject object) {
  MutexLocker ml(lock());

  // resolve the object
  oop o = JNIHandles::resolve_non_null(object);

  // for Classes get the tag from the klassOop
  return tag_for(this, klassOop_if_java_lang_Class(o));
}
```

1. Although my test only had one thread that was really under load it seems that this will scale even less once I add more threads and make heavy use of `GetTag`.

I wanted to use the tag to assign an id to certain objects and use it in my jvmti agent. Any ideas for a faster way accomplish that? Messing with the object header obvioulsy is not an option (to my knowledge).

NOTE: Most things should be done on C side as I do not want my Java agent to interfer with the application in any way. By interfer I even mean things like changing internal state of some central objects / classes (like `java.lang.StringCoding` for example), or leading to some classes being loaded, etc

`GetTag` is already used heavily throughout the current JVMTI agent, so I am looking for a faster way to get the tag or implement my own mechanism while staying on C side.

Comment: What about `IdentityHashMap`? The question is too broad actually. This depends on why you need ID at all and how you use it.

Comment: Good point, updated the question. In short: I need the id on C side without messing with whatever happens in Java. Actually now that I think about it...since I only need a unique identifier per object that does not change during life time shouldn't I be able to get the `oop` and use it as key directly? So the same way `get_tag`is doing it.

Comment: When you work with Java objects from C, you are basically limited by JNI and JVMTI functions. And they do have inevitable overhead. I'm afraid there are no other legal ways to access Java objects from a native agent. In particular, dealing with naked `oop` is illegal - this is just a raw pointer which may become invalid at any time because the objects can move.

Comment: I understand it is not public API but nevertheless would like to know what is going on under the hood. From what I saw today it looked like the `jobject`is only casted to `oop*` which then is dereferenced and later casted to ùnsigned int` to be used as hash in the tag map. But I must be missing something here. How can the oop be the key in a map when the object keeps moving around memory? If I understood correctly an `oop` points to an object header, but the object can be moved around by GC. I don't think that the keys in the maps are updated all the time an object is moved, right?

Comment: JVM knows about JvmtiTagMap and updates it whenever the objects are moved, see [`JvmtiTagMap::do_weak_oops`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/9ce27f0a4683/src/share/vm/prims/jvmtiTagMap.cpp#l3293). When JVM deals with raw pointers to Java heap, i.e. `oops`, it either ensures that no GC happens in between, or wraps oops into handles. `jobject` is an example of such oop handle.

Comment: Amazing, so the map get's updated indeed. Saw that as the only possibility but ruled that out as I thought it would be too much work. Now you answered my question (even if it wasn't the answer I was hoping for) without me being able to  accept it. What the best practice here on SO for that? Should I summarize below and answer myself?

Comment: Yes, it's OK to summarize and answer yourself, or I can just copy my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you work with Java objects from C, you are basically limited by JNI and JVMTI functions. And they do have inevitable overhead.

I'm afraid there are no other legal ways to access Java objects from a native agent. In particular, dealing with naked oop is illegal - this is just a raw pointer which may become invalid at any time because the objects can move.

JVM, however, can work with oops and even use the object address as a key in `JvmtiTagMap` as long as it updates the corresponding oops whenever the objects are moved. And HotSpot JVM indeed does this, see [JvmtiTagMap::do_weak_oops](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/9ce27f0a4683/src/share/vm/prims/jvmtiTagMap.cpp#l3293).

Comment: Thinking more about it, it makes sense that the JVM knows the map. In the end there is also cleanup needed once an object got gc'ed. Thanks a lot.