# Creating a custom JVM with larger object header

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

For various reasons I came to the conclusion that creating a custom JVM build might be the easiest option for what I am trying to achieve as there are simply too many things that are affecting performance really badly if done otherwise.

So I have the environment up and running, modified some simple things to generate some callbacks for what I need, played with some intrinsics, so far so good.

What I would like to know though is: What do the JVM experts here think about the feasibility of creating a custom VM that has a larger object header (e.g. 8 bytes more). `markOop.hpp` explains the content of the mark word in a pretty good way for the different flavours that exist (32bits, 64bits, 64bits with compressed oops) and I was wondering how hard it would be to extend the header so I can put some extra info on the objects (no tagging is not on option, see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53310123/faster-alternative-to-get-tags-for-objects-than-jvmti-gettag/53339528#53339528)).

So before digging deeper in this I was hoping that someone with experience in this could give some early feedback. Like is that a "suicide mission" because there are too many places all over where there are hard coded assumptions regarding the header size and the offsets? Or is all this fairly centralized and could be accomplished with reasonable effort without risking to break everything? Any pointer for what might need special care and what consequences this might have (besides the very obvious; more memory consumption)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible to enlarge the object header (I've seen such experiments before), though this won't be as easy as just adding a new field into [class oopDesc](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/9ce27f0a4683/src/share/vm/oops/oop.hpp#l59). I believe there are multiple places in JVM code that rely on the size of object header, but there are should not be too much. The size of object header already differs depending on the platform and the `UseCompressedOops` option, so the most places in the code already use relative offsets and won't suffer from a new field.

The other option is not to expand the header, but rather add a new fake field to `java.lang.Object` class. HotSpot already has the machinery for adding such fields, look for [InjectedField](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/9ce27f0a4683/src/share/vm/classfile/javaClasses.hpp#l1404) in the sources. However, this won't be trivial either. There are some hardcoded offsets for system classes, see [JavaClasses::check_offsets](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/9ce27f0a4683/src/share/vm/classfile/javaClasses.cpp#l3501). These need to be fixed, too.

The both approaches are roughly equal in terms of implementation efforts. In both cases I suggest to start with `debug` (not `fastdebug`) builds of JVM as they include many helpful assertions that will catch the possible offset problems early.

Having heard of your project, I think you also have the third option: give up "JVMTI only" requirement and rewrite some parts of the agent in Java leveraging the power of bytecode instrumentation and JIT compilation. Yes, this may slightly change Java code being executed and probably result in more classes loaded, but does this really matter, if from the user's perspective the impact will be even less than with JVMTI-only agent? I mean, the performance impact could be significantly less when there are no Java<->native switches, JVMTI overhead and so on. If the agent has low overhead and works with stock JVM, I guess it's not a big problem to make it ON in production in order to get its cool features, is it?

Comment: That's almost exactly what I implemented in the meantime actually :) I modified the class hierachy for all classes extending `java.lang.Object` to extend `MyObject` instead. The new class contains the extra fields I need. I excluded the classes that were listed in `javaClasses.cpp` and added special handling for those cases. Works as expected and so far without the need for a custom JVM build. We'll follow up on the object header question anyway, just to learn how it could be done.

Comment: Regarding doing things in Java,yes,part of the logic that uses the `MyObject` class is written in Java. The risk is, however, that we will influence our own engine. So we really need to ensure that the code we are writing does not lead to any event that will be traced or we need to disable the tracing for the current thread as soon as it enters our engine's code (this is how I did it in an earlier POC). Things that are considered are classloading & order, monitor entries, native calls and results, clinits, References, etc. If any of that gets out of sync between the runs we are in trouble.

Comment: @HaasipSatang Yes, this is a typical problem for many Java agents, and it is generally solved by disabling instrumentation while in the agent's code - exactly like you describe - for example, by setting a thread-local flag or something.

Comment: Since we are modifying so many core things anyway, I made it by just adding a `boolean` to `java.lang.Thread` that was indicating if event interception was disabled or not. While this works great to ignore events like monitor enter or native calls it does not really help if things like global counter get updated or some static fields get modified because of some code we use. Not saying it cannot be done, just saying it was tricky and led to a lot of unwanted side effects. Looking into that again though, as right now the main challenge is performance.